# Validate a list of strings against a list of Enums

Tags: java, enums

I have a `.properties` file containing a set of properties as key-value pairs. This is read into a configuration Enum class. This configuration class contains enums which correspond to the properties. I want to be able to catch a discrepancy between the two. Thus, if the properties file contains a property which does not exists in the class or the other way around.

In other words, I have an array of Enums:

`MyEnumClass[] enums = {E1,E2,E3}`

and an array of Strings representing the enums

`String[] properties = {"E1","E2","E3"}`

How can I find the intersection of the two? Preferably I would like to avoid streams.

Comment: Convert the `String`s into enums with `MyEnumClass.valueOf(String)`?

Comment: Or convert the enums to Strings by using their toString method (unless you have overidden toString yourself) or the name() method.

Comment: Do you really have an array of `MyEnumClass` objects? Or is it an array of `enum` types?

Comment: @Slaw Converting the enums to Strings is probably easier since there could be Strings which do not correspond to an enum.

Comment: @Socowi True. Though I would want an error to be thrown indicating the `.properties` file contains an unrecognized property. Assuming each possible property is supposed to have a corresponding enum constant.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to compute the intersection (changed the input to make the result obvious):

```
List<String> properties = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "E1", "E2" });
List<MyEnumClass> enums = Arrays.asList(new MyEnumClass[] 
                          { MyEnumClass.E2, MyEnumClass.E3 });

List<String> enumNames = new ArrayList<>();
for (MyEnumClass e : enums)
    enumNames.add(e.name());

List<String> intersection = new ArrayList<>(enumNames);
intersection.retainAll(properties);
System.out.println(intersection); //[E2]
```

And this can compute the difference of each from the other:

```
List<String> propDiff = new ArrayList<>(properties);
propDiff.removeAll(enumNames);
System.out.println(propDiff); //[E1]

List<String> enumDiff = new ArrayList<>(enumNames);
enumDiff.removeAll(properties);
System.out.println(enumDiff); //[E3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `EnumSet<MyEnumClass>` like so:

```
Set<MyEnumClass> all = EnumSet.allOf(MyEnumClass.class);
```

And then create another `EnumSet<MyEnumClass>` from your properties:

```
Set<MyEnumClass> loaded = EnumSet.noneOf(MyEnumClass.class);
for(String property : properties) {
    loaded.add(MyEnumClass.valueOf(property));
}
```

You can then check different things using `Collection.removeAll`, `Collection.addAll`, `Collection.retainAll`:

```
// all will now contain every element from loaded
all.addAll(loaded);
```

```
// all will now contain every element which was not contained in loaded
all.removeAll(loaded);
```

```
// all will now contain every element which was contained in loaded
all.retainAll(loaded);
```